# как получить позицию элемента во время остановки анимации javafx

Tags: java, javafx, анимация

есть узел node я двигаю его влево,в определенный момент останавливаю,потом запускаю анимацию которая двигает элемент вправо,но вот проблема - элемент начинает двигаться с нулевой точки,как сделать так чтобы нулевая точка передвинулась в точку окончания первой?Иначе говоря:когда первая анимация проигрывается, и её останавливают, неплохо было-бы получить ту самую точку, в которой она остановилась, для того чтобы вторая началась с этой же точки...

Comment: Приложите пример кода, который вы используете. Скорее всего, вы указываете начальную позицию ту, в которой нода была у вас до сдвига.

Comment: нет я имею ввиду позицию которая нода  получила во время анимации,при её остановке.

Comment: тобишь двигалась-двигалась-двигалась,и остановилась.в n-ную секунду,и надо получить позицию при её остановке...